# Prevent break line in URL

Tags: html, css, line-breaks, nowrap

how can I prevent line break in a URL in Mozilla Firefox. With using CSS *white-space: nowrap;* ? Any other solutions? Thanx.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeNJKW

```css
.container {
  width:  275px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  This is a URL: <span class = "">http://www.google.com/helloworld</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any other solution to fix it in Firefox than using this css?

Answer (score 1):

nowrap style is not applied in your code, should be:

```
This is a URL: <span class = "">http://www.google.com/helloworld</span>
```

->

```
This is a URL: <span class = "nowrap">http://www.google.com/helloworld</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like that?

```
.container {
  width:  275px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: visible;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://codepen.io/sheldonled/pen/eJoqWR